# Get the last 100 inserted records in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I want to retrieve the last 100 inserted records in sql server 2008.

Please correct my code.
Pkey in the table testContext.testDetailRecords is an identity column.

```
var pkeys = (from tests in testContext.testDetailRecords
                         where tests.Pkey > (select max(tests.Pkey)-100 from testContext.testDetailRecords))
                                select tests.Pkey).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
var pkeys = testContext.testDetailRecords
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.PKey)
                 .Take(100)
                 .Select(x => x.PKey);
```

This should roughly translate to SQL

```
SELECT TOP 100 PKey
FROM testDetailRecords
ORDER BY PKey DESC
```

Comment: One more question, can I change .Select(x=>x.Pkey) as .ToList()

Comment: @Love - you can change it to whatever you want. Its your code ;) You original question selected just the `PKey` field at the end, if you want the entire entity either leave of the `Select` for an `IQueryable<TestDetailRecord>` or add `ToList()` to materialize the result to a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
var pkeys = (from tests in testContext.testDetailRecords
             orderby tests.Pkey descending
             select tests.Pkey).Take(100).ToList();
```

Comment: Oh thats ok, no need to be sorry. I just feel funny correcting people's answers directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = testContext.testDetailRecords.OrderByDescending(tests.Pkey).Take(100).Select(...);
```